# How to write french in fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, french

i need to write some specific french caracteres like é è ê ... etc

this is the cell :

```
$this->Cell(50,7,"Référence ".$info["reference"]);
```

and this is the output :

[image]

**Is there a solution ?**

Comment: See [F.A.Q](http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q3) number 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use utf8_decode()

```
$this->Cell(50,7,utf8_decode("Référence ".$info["reference"]));
```

[image]